# Adding many redirect rules to web.config

Tags: iis

I have deleted quite some pages from my website which I want to permanently redirect (301) to other pages, using my web.config file.
What is the simplest syntax to redirect one page to another one? I tried this:

```
    <rule name="name manager redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="https://*jkp-ads.com/OfficeMarketPlaceNM-EN.asp"/>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://jkp-ads.com/excel-name-manager.asp"/>
    </rule>
```

But that does not appear to work?

Comment: You can find tons of examples from search engines, but keep in mind of common mistakes, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: Believe me, I know how to use Google and I had a hard time finding examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the part of match url. It doesn't contain `http://domain:port`. It only match URI. So the rule should be

```
<rule name="name manager redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="OfficeMarketPlaceNM-EN.asp"/>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://jkp-ads.com/excel-name-manager.asp"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate!

Comment: I'm afraid it does not work even though I've literally copied the xml bit from your post. Grrr. Try visiting https://jkp-ads.com/officemarketplacenm-en.asp, it will take you to my custom 404 page.

Comment: Are the domain names in the URLs before and after redirection the same domain? If not then a reverse proxy rule should be created instead of a blank rule. When you entered original URL in browser, if it changed and changed to what? Using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to check which step of redirection caused failure and result in 404.

Comment: Never mind, I've got it sorted. Human error: My website editing program wasn't uploading my web.config. Switching to filezilla ensured the web.config being uploaded and now it works. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can mark it as correct answer to help others with same issue.